# How do I solve GET 500 (Internal Server Error) error?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, internal-server-error

[After the + button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBEZ6.png)

[The quantity increases when I refresh the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moyNA.png)

The console shows the 500 Internal Server Error every time I click the + button. Also, the ajax coding for the button only works when I refresh the page. Could someone enlighten me what causes this error and how to solve it?

related section in cartpage.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="border rounded p-4 m-4" style="width:1000px;">
        <p class="display-4 pl-4 ml-4">Shopping Cart</p>
        <hr>
        
        <table class="table table-fixed">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="w-5">Image</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Price</th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
        
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                {% for cart in cart %}
                    <td><ion-icon name="close-outline"></ion-icon></td>
              
                    <input type="hidden" name="prodid" value="{{product.ProdID}}" id="prodid" class="prodid">
                    <td class="w-5"><image src="{{ cart.product.ProdPic.url }}" style="height:80px; width:65px;" class="rounded-circle"></td>
                    <td>{{cart.product.ProdName}}</td>
                    
                       
                        <td class="cart-product-quantity">
                            
                            <input type="button" pid = "{{ cart.product.ProdID }}" class="minus-cart btn btn-light btn-circle btn-sm" value="-"></input>
                            <span id="quantity" min="1">{{ cart.item_qty }}</span>
                            <input type="button" pid = "{{ cart.product.ProdID }}" class="plus-cart btn btn-light btn-circle btn-sm" value="+"></input>
   
                        </td>
                            
                    <td>RM{{cart.product.ProdPrice}}</td>
                </tr>
                  
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
                
    </table>
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- links to popper js and bootstrap js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.plus-cart').click (function(){
            var id=$(this).attr("pid").toString();
            console.log(id)

            $.ajax({
            type : "get",
            url : "{% url 'plus_cart' %}",
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {
            prod_id : id
            },
            success:function(data){
            console.log(data)
            }

            })

            })

        });

    </script>





{% endblock %}
```

related views.py

```
def cartpage(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.all()
    subtotal = sum(item.product.ProdPrice * item.item_qty for item in cart)
    totalprice = subtotal + 3

    dict={
        'cart':cart,
        'subtotal' : subtotal,
        'totalprice' : totalprice
    } 
    return render (request,"cartpage.html",{'cart': cart, 'subtotal': subtotal, 'totalprice' : totalprice})

def plus_cart(request):
    product_id = request.GET['prod_id']
    cart = Cart.objects.get(product=product_id)

    cart.item_qty = cart.item_qty + 1
    cart.save()
    data = {
        'item_qty' : item_qty
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path("",views.welcome,name="welcome"),
    path('homepage/',views.homepage,name="homepage"),
    path('cartpage/',views.cartpage,name='cartpage'),
    path('add_to_cart/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
    path('plus_cart/',views.plus_cart,name='plus_cart'),
]
```

p/s : every time I click the + button, it will appear like this in my command prompt:

[is not defined error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgqwZ.png)

I have tried changing the query link and everything but it does not work at all. Please help a newbie here :)

Comment: Next time try posting your errors in text format. It helps us a lot reproducing your error. :-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You just have small logical problem in your `plus_cart` function:

```
def plus_cart(request):
    product_id = request.GET['prod_id']
    cart = Cart.objects.get(product=product_id)

    cart.item_qty = cart.item_qty + 1
    cart.save()
    data = {
        'item_qty' : cart.item_qty #here
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

just replace `'item_qty' : item_qty` with `'item_qty' : cart.item_qty`

Comment: I confirm. This is what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you! It returns {item_qty: 4} in the console. However the quantity will be updated to 4 only when I refresh the page. Any solution?

Comment: @123234 well you can get the input data(value) as well so after success, just update the inputs value,

Comment: @123234 I think you can add a method to automatically refresh after clicking on the webpage tag.